# C# MSAccess parametrized SELECT query raises IndexOutOfRange exception

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, parameters, oledb

Im trying to re-work my SQL queries into safe alternatives to prevent SQL injection attacks but having difficulty pulling from the database using these parameters.

This is C#, using an MS Access database and OleDB connections.

I have the following query:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select ?, [ID] FROM Agent_Skills", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 100) {
    Value = ScriptName
});

reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader[ScriptName].ToString() != "0")
    {
        selectedSkillIDs.Add(reader["ID"].ToString());
        selectedPriority.Add(reader[i].ToString());
    }
}
```

When I run this query I get an IndexOutOfRange exception from

```
reader[ScriptName].ToString()
```

The ScriptName variable is required as this is going to change multiple times through the scripts daily cycle so cannot be static.

If I swap out ScriptName to [1] I'll get each row as the loop iterates through my results, but i need these to correlate to each other as I need specific pairs of data.

I'm at a loss as to how to use parameters in a query like this to actually get the results, Google brings up plenty of results for UPDATE, DELETE and other input queries.

Do I need to use parameters like this for a simple data return query? If so how do I go about this?

Comment: Probably unlikely that you have a column called `?` in your database. Yes, you should use parameters for a select query. If you use the actual column name from your Agent_Skills table in your Select instead of ? it should work.

Comment: dont use `new OleDbParameter("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 100)` but specify a parameter name instead of `?`

Comment: column names cannot be parametrized. values in `where` conditions can. what do you really need to achieve? a variable column name would be fine to inject into the query text as long as it is not user-supplied.

Comment: I need two columns of data to be returned so i can then filter some things out and act with the relevant data, both columns contain just text and are simply strings of numbers up to 3 characters long.

The column names will be user input _eventually_ but i could parametrize (< spelling?) the input at a later stage (when I develop it) to make this query somewhat easier to handle

Comment: If users are going to select columns, they should be choosing from existing column names.

Comment: Users will be adding new columns at the end game, each column is a script for somthing else which each cell being a priority relating to a skill number (another column)

If i validate the user input am i right in thinking i dont need to do anything here as this piece of code is not user related but all automated?